# Containers Being Pushed Down

Tags: html, css

I have this issue where when i create new content in each container the one next to it is being pushed down causing it to screw with my page

```css
.about {
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#fastdel {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}

#dollar {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}

#code {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="whybuy">WHY BUY FROM US</h1>
<div id="largebox">
  <div id="box1">
    <img src="images/code.png" class="about">
    <h1 id="code">High Quality Accounts</h1>
    <div id="box2">
      <img src="images/dollar.png" class="about">
      <h1 id="dollar">Low Prices</h1>
      <div id="box3">
        <img src="images/clock.png" class="about">
        <h1 id="fastdel">Fast Delivery</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8w09v5Lp/

Comment: the code you provided doesn't match the screenshot https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWJvrL see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Why are you nesting each div inside the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

First fix your html, your tags are not closing properly
Second, stop using id's everywhere.

```css
.about {
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.box{
  display:inline-block;
}
#fastdel {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}

#dollar {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}

#code {
  color: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="whybuy">WHY BUY FROM US</h1>
<div id="largebox">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/code.png" class="about">
    <h1 id="code">High Quality Accounts</h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      <img src="images/dollar.png" class="about">
      <h1 id="dollar">Low Prices</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
        <img src="images/clock.png" class="about">
        <h1 id="fastdel">Fast Delivery</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```